# How to access locally stored inventory data?

Tags: blockchain, message, inventory

I'm looking for objects in the source code of Bitcoin Core that record all block inventories distinguished by their miners - **Is there a container that keeps track of blocks on `chainActive` and stores it to disk?**
**I'm trying to find analogs for what is defined as private and public branch in the [paper about the Selfish Mine Attack](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1311.0243v5.pdf).**

*NOTE:*
As I noticed by some tests, `vInventoryToSend` and `setInventoryKnown` don't seem to be very helpul in their actual form:
`vInventoryToSend` **temporarily** stores only freshly self-mined blocks and `setInventoryKnown` stores all blocks, no matter if self-mined, received or even outside of `chainActive`.